# Why is the compiler not warning about definitions with no names?

Tags: c++

The following C++ code does nothing (using GCC 4.4.3) - it does not print the text:

```
struct MyStruct { MyStruct() { cout << "Hello" << endl; } };

void foo() {
  MyStruct ();
}
```

I think this is not so obvious... Let alone the danger of forgetting to give a variable name. Is there a compiler option/warning to forbid compilation of such code or is there any hidden secret behind allowing it?

**Edit:** I am sorry. The version above `MyStruct();` acutally prints. The version which is not printing is:

```
void bar() {
    MyStruct a();
}
```

So now I am a bit confused.

Comment: Prints for me: http://codepad.org/g96sG1lZ . Maybe g++ needs certain flags or it thinks that `MyStruct();` is a declaration of a function with an omitted return type. Or maybe you didn't call `foo()` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a declaration, because in `MyStruct ();`, the `MyStruct` would be part of the *decl-specifier-seq* and forms a *type-name* therein. And then `()` can only be a *function-declarator*. This requires that there is a *declarator-id* specified, which in your case is not. A special syntactical form is needed to allow such a syntax in declaring a constructor. But such syntactical exceptions are not made in a *declaration-statement*.

So this construct cannot be a declaration. It is parsed as an expression which specifies a functional cast creating a temporary of type `MyStruct`.

If the compiler does not print *Hello* it is either non-conforming or you are not calling `foo` in your program.

---

Your edit also does not specify a declaration without a name. It instead specifies a declaration that *does* have a name. It declares a function that is called `a`. The compiler has no way that you meant something else by this.

```
MyStruct a();
```

It could in an effort deduce this by having a recovering rule when it later discovers errors in your code such as the following

```
a.f();
```

If you have this in your code to try and call a member function and "a" is a function, the compiler could check to see if `MyStruct` contains a member `f` such that this expression is well-formed. But what if you just forgot to place parentheses? The following would be valid for the above declared function that returns a `MyStruct`, assuming a suitably declared member `f`.

```
a().f();
```

So in effect, the compiler can't really know what you mean.

Comment: I would expect `MyStruct a();` to be a definition calling the default constructor, like ` MyStruct a(1);` calling a constructor with one argument.

Comment: @Danvil others may expect it to be a factory function returning a `MyStruct`. What about `std::string getName();` ?

Comment: @Danvil : `MyStruct a(1)` actually creates an object `a` but `MyStruct a()` doesn't. Please read his post carefully.

Comment: @Johannes: In global or namespace scope ok ..., but *inside* a function?

Comment: @Prasoon: I understood his post well. Just wondering for the reason behind this design decision.

Comment: @Danvil : Can't you declare a function inside another? Well in C++ you can.

Comment: I never declared a function inside a function in my C++ life. Perhaps I missed something - do you have a (useful) example for this? Nevertheless again my question: Does there exists a compiler option warning me that I am not defining an object but declaring a function?

Comment: @Danvil You can declare functions that you define in namespace scope (and variables) inside a function. Like `void f() { extern int A; string g(); }` declaring `A` and `g`, both of which are members of the same namespace. The C language is flexible like that (C doesn't know the `type()` syntax, so it has no reason to worry about ambiguities), and C++ needs to be compatible to it here.

Comment: @Danvil moreover, since C does not have a scope resolution operator, it's the only way to make a function visible that is hidden by another identifier in a surrounding block in C: `void f(void) { ... } void g(void) { int f = 0; { void f(void); f(); } }`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have "a declaration with no name" in your code. You have a completely valid *expression* `MyStruct()`. It is not a declaration, once again, it is an expression statement. If it doesn't print anything, it mist be the effect of optimization: in C++ it is generally allowed to eliminate temporaries, even if their constructors/destructors have side effects. (Although this context is not really one where such elimination is allowed. Are you sure you actually execute that expression statement?)

Answer (score 3):

`MyStruct a();` declares a function `a` that takes no arguments and returns a `MyStruct`.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I think the temporary is elided [due to compiler optimization], hence you don't see the call to the c-tor.</s>

Your code is syntactically perfect so there is no need for the compiler to give a warning [as such].

**EDIT** [As per the edits in the OP]

> MyStruct a();

The above is parsed as the declaration of a function `a` return a `MyStruct` object and taking no parameters.

Comment: Would it optimize it out even though it's printing something?

Comment: @JoshD: I am not a compiler expert but I don't think something like this is possible. I am not very sure though. Somebody please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, temporary objects are perfectly legals. So there is no reasons to warn here.